# Merging PDF in Java is not working

Tags: java, pdf, byte, bytearrayoutputstream

I am writing a function that takes as inputs a list of PDFs that are already converted into `ByteArrayOutputStream` and the destination `filepath\name.pdf`.
But I am getting errors and the document is not saved.

```
Public Void mergePDF(<ByteArrayOutputStream> src3,String DestinationFileName ){
    PDFMergerUtility PDFmerger3 = new PDFMergerUtility();
    PDFmerger3.setDestinationFileName(DestinationFileName);

    for(ByteArrayOutputStream bos:src3){
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        PDFmerger.addSource(is);
    }
    try {
        PDFmerger.mergeDocuments(null);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }// end of the Function
}
```

Comment: show us the stack trace please

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
 at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFile.createBuffer(ScratchFile.java:421)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:964)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:885)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:259)
 at mergePDFModule.testing.main(testing.java:180)

Comment: the exact problem is that I am not getting any new PDF named with the DestinationFileName that I have declared in my main,